# Reading file input data and loading it into an Array

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that reads data from a file and inputs it into an array. It seems like it should work, however I get an odd output from the program (no error, it runs, just gives me a weird result).

Here's my code:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("../Computer/src/computers/computer.txt"));
    String[] comps = new String[2];

    int i = 0;

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        comps[i] = s.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
    s.close();

    System.out.println(comps);
```

The output that I get is:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3d62b333
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Also, my text file looks like this, if it's a problem with my text file:

```
12344555 Dell Intel 499.99
23623626 Asus AMD 299.99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading file correctly, but printing array in incorrect way.

Use below to print your array.

```
    for(int j =0;j<comps.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(comps[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a big help.

Answer (score 4):

You can't print an array like that. The output you're getting is the default `toString()` from `Object` which outputs the hashcode.

You have to iterate through it and print each `String`

```
for (String s : comps)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```